# fast.ai name ImageDataBunch not found

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, fast-ai

I am working on an image recognition system, and was having trouble with fast.ai loading data.

My code is:

```
from fastai.vision import *
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(42)

data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder('D:\\Apple-detector\\data\\fruits', train=".", valid_pct=0.2, ds_tfms=get_transforms(), size=450, num_workers=4, bs = 16).normalize(imagenet_stats)

print(data.classes())
```

And it returns the error:  `NameError: name 'ImageDataBunch' is not defined`

Comment: please always post full errors, not just the bottom line

Comment: Also, this error means `ImageDataBunch` is not defined. no where did you import or define it.